# Matplotlib fill between horizontal threshold line and plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill

How can I fill between my plot and a horizontal line that's not zero?

I've used the fill_betwee() method and it detects the correct points but it fills all the way from the x axis to my plot

[image]

Here's the code that I've done so far:

```
plt.fill_between(df.index, df['Data'], where= (df['Data'] > 205), color='orange')
```

Comment: Try this; `plt.fill_between(df.index, 205, df.Data, where=(df.Data > 205), color='orange')`

Comment: that totally worked!, if you want to submit the answer I'll mark it as approved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill between matplotlib, y0:start value, y1:end value,Where:range limited.

```
plt.fill_between(df.index, 205, df.Data, where=(df.Data > 205), color='orange')
```

Comment: @ortunoa Thank you for giving me the opportunity to respond.

Answer (score 0):

not sure but..

add a list with the same length as df["data"] with 205 for every entry.

```
plt.fill_between(df.index, df['Data'], [205, 205, ...], where= (df['Data'] > 205), color='orange')
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that too and it didn't work, it looked like a vertical line at 205 on the x axis

Comment: Can you show a picture of that? And/Or can you post df.index and df["Data"] here?

Comment: Yea how can I post the data here? It's around 5k rows. Index is simply, just auto increment, 1,2,3..

Comment: The problem should stay, if you only take the first 100 entries (of df.index and df["Data"]), right? Try that and if it shows the same problem (which would be good i guess) then send all lists with 100 entries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).